# Bitmap does not scale accurately when screen size changes

Tags: android, bitmap, scale, android-bitmap

I have a created a scaled bitmap scaledfish[0] for my bitmap fish[0], so that when the screen size is changed my program will automatically scale the bitmap to the new screen size. My code follows:

```
fish[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.charactertwo);
scaledfish[0] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fish[0], ((canvasWidth/720)*45), ((canvasHeight/1232)*45), false);
```

For reference, this is what the bitmap should always be scaled too:
[Perfectly scaled bitmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksgdz.jpg)

The size of the screen that the original bitmap height and width were created on is 720x1232, and the height and width of fish[0] is 45x45 (which is why I am multiplying scaledfish[0] by 45 for both height and width). When I use this code and write

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(scaledfish[0], fishX, fishY, null);
```

The bitmap is half as big and half as wide, it looks like this:

[Half as wide and half as long as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcD8y.jpg)

When I switch the code to this:

```
 scaledfish[0] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fish[0], ((canvasWidth/720)*90), ((canvasHeight/1232)*90),false);
```

On the screen size 720x1232, it works perfectly, great. But, when I switch the screen size to 1440x2560, the bitmap is perfectly wide, but half as long, looks like this:

[Perfectly wide but half as long as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEw8E.png)

And, just to provide completely clarity, when I switch the code to equal this:

```
 scaledfish[0] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fish[0], ((canvasWidth/720)*90), ((canvasHeight/1232)*180),false);
```

The screen size 1440x2560 works perfectly. Great. But when, the screen size once again becomes 720x1232, the bitmap is perfectly wide, but 2 times as long as it should be, looks like this:

[Perfectly wide but 2 times as long as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BsPN.jpg)

SO, to summarize the whole problem, the bitmap is only scaled properly on screen 1 (720x1232) when:

- X value is double the size of the original bitmap
- Y value is double the size of the original bitmap

And it is only scaled properly on screen 2 (1440x2560) when:

- X value is double the size of the original bitmap
- Y value is **4** times the size of the original bitmap.

If anyone could provide me with the solution for the scale/proportion to make it work the same for every screen, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.